# A limit tends to Euler's constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, euler-mascheroni-constant

Is this limit obvious that it is tended to Euler's constant?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}H_{k}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)}-\ln n=\gamma$$

Where $H_k$ is the [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $\gamma$; [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

Comment: A sequence may *tend* to something, a limit just *is* something. What is the actual question here? "*Is it trivial that [...]?*" Well, more or less.

Comment: I just want to know does this limit tends to Euler's constant or it is false. Numerically it seems to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that using [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nH_k\left(\frac1k+\frac1{k+1}\right)
&=\sum_{k=1}^nH_k\left(H_{k+1}-H_{k-1}\right)\tag1\\
&=H_{n+1}H_n-H_1H_0\tag2\\[9pt]
&=H_{n+1}H_n\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, since [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) are monotonically increasing,
$$
H_n^2\le H_{n+1}H_n\le H_{n+1}^2\tag4
$$
and by the definition of the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant),
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(H_n-\log(n))=\lim_{n\to\infty}(H_{n+1}-\log(n))=\gamma\tag5
$$
The [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) completes the answer.